# System of Pell's equations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

Let $a$, $b$ and $k$ be positive integers.
I want to prove that the only solution of the system
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rclr}
2k^2+1&=&a^2&(1)\\
6k^2+1&=&b^2&(2)
\end{array}
\right.$$
is $(k,a,b)=(2,3,5)$.

I checked by computer that there was no solution with $3\leq k\leq10^8$.

I know that the values of $k$ which satisfy $(1)$ are the terms of the sequence $(k_n)$ defined by
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
k_0=2\\
k_1=12\\
k_{n+2}=6k_{n+1}-k_n
\end{array}
\right.$$
and that the values of $k$ which satisfy (2) are those of the sequence $(k'_n)$ defined by
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
k'_0=2\\
k'_1=20\\
k'_{n+2}=10k'_{n+1}-k'_n
\end{array}
\right.$$

but I cannot prove that if $m\geq1$ and $n\geq1$, then $k_n\neq k'_m$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $a$, $b$ and $k$ be positive integers such that
\begin{eqnarray}
2k^2+1&=&a^2,\\
6k^2+1&=&b^2.
\end{eqnarray}
Then clearly $k$ is coprime to $a$ and $b$ and
$$a^2+(2k)^2=b^2,$$
so $(a,2k,b)$ is a primitive Pythagorean triple. This means there exist coprime integers $m>n>0$, not both odd, such that
\begin{eqnarray}
a&=&m^2-n^2,\\
k&=&mn,\\
b&=&m^2+n^2.
\end{eqnarray}
Plugging this back into the first equation of the original system we see that
$$1=m^4-4m^2n^2+n^4,$$
which is a Thue equation, for which effective methods exist. PARI/GP tells me that the unique integral solution with $m>n>0$ is $(m,n)=(2,1)$, corresponding to $a=3$, $k=2$, $b=5$.

Comment: Do you think we could adapt your solution to prove that the only solution to the system $\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
2k^2+1&=&a^2\\
20k^2+1&=&b^2
\end{array}
\right.$ is $(k,a,b)=(2,3,9)$ ?

Comment: The exact same method works. Maybe the corresponding Thue equation has other solutions; give it a try yourself!

Comment: But $20-2=18$ is not a square.

Comment: You still get a smooth conic defined over $\Bbb{Q}$ that has a point, so you can parametrize its solutions in the same way, and again get a Thue equation.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: could you add the PARI/CP commands you used to solve the equation?

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
&&\texttt{t = thueinit( x^4 - 4*x^2 + 1 );}\\
&&\texttt{thue( t, 1 )}
\end{eqnarray*}